# find multi line values using regular expression and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string in the memory and would like to quickly remove all the debug events from it. The regular expression that I am using also grabs other events until it finds the DEBUG event. So in this sample it is capturing more than one event. In the following XML it is capturing from the beginning to the 3rd event. It should only select the third event for this input below.

I am not trying to parse an XML here. I just want to remove the debug events (>95% of events) from huge data. I have tried doing the same using parser and it times out on a tiny SBC. If you have other ways to solve this in JavaScript (outside browser) I am open for any suggestions.

**INPUT:**

```
<event type="app">
    <header>
        <info>1234</info>
    </header>
    <body>
        <severity type="INFO">message</severity>
    </body>
</event>
<event type="app">
    <header>
        <info>1235</info>
    </header>
    <body>
        <severity type="ERROR">message</severity>
    </body>
</event><event type="app">
    <header>
        <info>1236</info>
    </header>
    <body>
        <severity type="DEBUG">message</severity>
    </body>
</event>
<event type="app">
    <header>
        <info>1237</info>
    </header>
    <body>
        <severity type="ERROR">message</severity>
    </body>
</event>
```

**regex:**
`<event type="app"(.|\n|\r\n)*?<severity type="DEBUG"(.|\n|\r\n)*?<\/event>`

I have this sample online at:

https://regex101.com/r/JW3DWE/1

Thank you!

Comment: Regular expressions are ill-suited for processing XML. I suggest using an XML parser for this task.

Comment: @oobug I understand that regex is not well suited for XML. The host running this task does not have lot of CPU power so I am trying to remove the unnecessary data from the string 
and then parse using XML parser. This events data is huge and has lots of debug events that I don't need and takes lot of time processing this XML and it is timing out.

Comment: XML parsers often have capabilities to iterate through XML instead of loading the entire XML document into memory. What programming language are you using?

Comment: @oobug I am using javascript

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/a9utSI/1) what you want?

Comment: @Toto Perfect! this is what I was looking for. I was trying the same concept (negative look ahead) but wasn't working for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @oobug please remove the down vote as this was not the parsing question. Thanks

Comment: @Bharat it wasn't my downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always prefer using a parser when dealing with HTML/XML.

For this specific case, you can use regex like this:

Match:

```
<event type="app">(?:(?!<\/event>)[\s\S])*<severity type="DEBUG">[\s\S]*?<\/event>
```

and replace with nothing.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/a9utSI/1)